# Encrypted Ubuntu 16.04.03 partition no longer boots

Tags: 16.04, boot, encryption, cryptsetup

I have a hard drive with two copies of Ubuntu on it, living on separate partitions. One is running Ubuntu 16.04.02 and is not encrypted. It is doing fine. The other is running Ubuntu 16.04.03 and the whole root and swap area is encrypted with LUKS. It used to boot fine after I entered the unlock password. The most recent time I successfully booted this encrypted Ubuntu seems to be Jan 10th. I don't remember if I had automatic updates or automatic security updates turned on, but I suspect I had one of them turned on, because it is behaving differently now:

Now when I try to boot the encrytped Ubuntu, it does not boot after entering the unlock password. If I enter an incorrect password, it tells me that the password is incorrect. If I enter the correct password, it does not complain, but it does hang. This is true from the splash screen, if I'm booting into recovery mode, or if I switch from the decryption splash screen to a textual console with ESC.

From the working Ubuntu install, I can decrypt and mount the encrypted volume correctly. From poking around the rootfs, everything looks fine to me. I'm not sure what to look at to determine if anything is wrong.

---

potentially helpful logs, etc.:

I took a look at syslog in /var/log to see if it was complaining about anything that would obviously cause my system to stop booting. I glanced through it a bit but don't see what might have caused the problem. There is some interesting stuff about apt not getting a lock file at the end? Could that have botched an Ubuntu update process? Here's all of the [syslog](https://gist.github.com/sinback/283e10daf28761302bc18d2f68d5c4d2) from the last day the machine booted.

From recovery mode there is lots of dmesg output that I can't capture because it zooms by pretty fast. If somebody can tell me where to find it on the hard drive, I can attach it. [The end looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2FGW.jpg)

From the text console I access with ESC, there is much less output, but before the prompt for a password there is something interesting about the size of some device and UEFI. [It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M23yT.jpg)

---

Ideally I'd like to be able to repair my system and boot it again so that I don't have to do work re-configuring my applications, etc. I'm already backing up my home folder from that partition and I can do a reinstall of Ubuntu if necessary, but I'd like to avoid that if there's an easy fix. I haven't backed up other images of this encrypted hard drive, perhaps because I'm an idiot.

The kernel I'm trying to boot is 4.13.0-26-generic.

Comment: Know nothing about encrypted partition. Just shocked by the screenshot. It's really clear, far clearer than most did, wondering what camera in your hand...

Comment: It's a Nexus 6P phone's camera :)